# Openwrt - router ips on different subnets accessible by default?

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, openwrt, subnet

I have an Openwrt Router in Default Config plus those changes:
Lan Network - 192.168.1.0/24
Admin Network - 193.168.2.0/24
Wan Network - 192.168.0.0/24

Iptables

Default Forward Deny

Admin+Lan

Forward Deny

In/Out Allow

Lan to Wan Forward Allow

Wan

Input Deny

Output Allow

Masquerading

Dropbear

Listen only on admin interface

EDIT:
The switch is actually split into 3 segments with untagged Vlans. Wan, Lan, Admin. So the different interfaces are not all on the same Layer 2 device.

When I connect my laptop to the lan interface I cant reach devices in the admin zone as expected.
But if it is an IP of the router itself, I can reach it in every subnet.
So I can connect to services on all of the router IPs.
192.168.0.2, 192.167.1.1, 192.168.2.1

If I do ssh user@192.168.1.1 --> connection refused

If I do ssh user@192.168.2.1 --> I get a working ssh connection.

I dont want the ssh service accessible from Lan.
Or for that matter no network service on another subnet than intended.
What do I miss to make that zone distinction work even on the routers own IPs?

I used an Iptables rule to block everything from lan going to 192.168.2.1. This works but I want a setting that prevents this for all future networks.

Comment: TPLink wdr4300 (ar71xx)

Comment: If its an option to you, specify the interface that is allowed, eg iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP; iptables -I INPUT -i ADMINIF -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT    (Order is important, with the -I line, rules are added to the top, so you need to ensure the drop comes before the accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this, just edit in /etc/config/firewall file
Before

```
config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'lan'
```

After

```
config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT' 
    option network 'lan'    

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest_port '53'
    option name 'lan DNS'
    option src 'lan'

config rule
    option enabled '1'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option name 'lan DHCP'
    option src 'lan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '67-68'
```

This will help you to reject shh to your router through lan.

Comment: If you find this helpful, then tick as a write answer so anyone can refer this.

Comment: No you have to just replace, options input and forward to reject in config zone option lan.